# Boot repair Error Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, gparted, bios, boot-repair

I am facing some problems after I rebooted my computer. It started to fail during booting. I am not sure what is the exact problem however I have noticed some weird problems in my BIOS setup, where the keyboard does not function properly. However I tried to use Boot repair from an Ubuntu USB and I got the following error:

> The boot files of [Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Here is the link for the Boot-repair report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25966527/

I have seen from other posts that this error regarding the partition is sometimes misleading. I do not have a dual boot on this system.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by starting the ubuntu in upstart mode. Upstart mode gave me an error about fstab which I have edited some time ago to mount another harddrive. After I manually deleted the UID for the  second hard drive from fstab, the system started boot properly.

Maybe the BIOS was trying to read from the second hard drive all the time because of the fstab and that is why the boot-repair gave me the error about "boot files are far from the start of the disk"